# can't set a map async

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, youtube-api

I'm trying to read a file from s3, which store names of artists and get the top 10 songs on youtube.

I am able to get the s3 data and i am able to get the data using youtube data api,
I want to store the data in a array of objects I have created which are called singer.

```
console.log("Loading up the best code ever!!!");

var fs = require('fs');
// Load the SDK for JavaScript
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
var Singer = require('./Singer')
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-1" });
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials();
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
console.log("after S3");


// Create the parameters for calling createBucket
var bucketParams = {
    Bucket: 'pc-backend-exercises',
    Key: 'toSearch.json',
    ResponseContentType: 'application/json'
};

/// youtube part
var YTAPI = require('node-youtubeapi-simplifier');

var APIKEY = 'kekekek' 

YTAPI.setup(APIKEY);

var singers = [];
var print = function printJson() {

    console.log('entered printJson')
    console.log(singers);
    var results = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < singers.length; i++) {
        results[singers[i].name] = singers[i];

    }
    JSON.stringify(results);
    console.log(results);
}


s3.getObject(bucketParams, function (err, data) {
    // Handle any error and exit
    console.log('download json file from s3');
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        return err;
    }
    var fileContents = data.Body.toString();
    var json = JSON.parse(fileContents);

    for (var i = 0; i < json.Search.artists.length; i++) {
        var newSinger = new Singer(json.Search.artists[i]);
        singers.push(newSinger);
    }

    search10TopForASinger(print);

});

function search10TopForASinger(print) {
    console.log('entered search10TopForASinger ')
    for (var i = 0; i < singers.length; i++) {
        //Gets only 10 results
        var songsMap = singers[i].songs;
        YTAPI.searchFunctions.simpleSearch(singers[i].name).then(
            function (data) {
                setMap(data,songsMap);
            });
    }
    print();
}

function setMap(data, songs) {
    console.log('entered setMap')
    var size = 10;
    if (data.length < 10) {
        size = data.length;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       songs.set(i, data[i].title);
    }
    console.log(songs);
}
```

I made some changes and have better results:

```
Loading up the best code ever!!!
after S3
download json file from s3
entered search10TopForASinger
entered printJson
[ Singer { name: 'Katy', songs: Map {} },
  Singer { name: 'Madonna', songs: Map {} },
  Singer { name: 'Rihanna', songs: Map {} },
  Singer { name: 'Beyonce', songs: Map {} } ]
{ Katy: Singer { name: 'Katy', songs: Map {} },
  Madonna: Singer { name: 'Madonna', songs: Map {} },
  Rihanna: Singer { name: 'Rihanna', songs: Map {} },
  Beyonce: Singer { name: 'Beyonce', songs: Map {} } }
entered setMap
Map {
  0 => 'Madonna\'s Greatest Hits',
  1 => 'Madonna - Bitch I\'m Madonna ft. Nicki Minaj',
  2 => 'Madonna - La Isla Bonita (Official Music Video)',
  3 => 'Madonna - Hung Up (Official Music Video)',
  4 => 'madonna',
  5 => 'Madonna - Like A Prayer (Official Music Video)',
  6 => 'Madonna - Hollywood (Official Music Video)',
  7 => 'Madonna - Vogue (video)',
  8 => 'Madonna - Get Stupid (Studio version)',
  9 => 'Madonna - The Power Of Good-Bye' }
entered setMap
Map {
  0 => 'KatyPerryVEVO',
  1 => 'Katy Perry - Hey Hey Hey (Official)',
  2 => 'Katy Perry - Swish Swish (Official) ft. Nicki Minaj',
  3 => 'Katy Perry - Bon Appétit (Official) ft. Migos',
  4 => 'Katy Perry - Chained To The Rhythm (Official) ft. Skip Marley',
  5 => 'Katy Perry - Dark Horse (Official) ft. Juicy J',
  6 => 'LustreLux',
  7 => 'Katy Perry - The One That Got Away (Official)',
  8 => 'Katy Perry - Roar (Official)',
  9 => 'Katy Perry - Wide Awake (Official)' }
entered setMap
Map {
  0 => 'DJ Khaled - Wild Thoughts ft. Rihanna, Bryson Tiller',
  1 => 'Rihanna Greatest Hits ---- Rihanna Best Song New 2017',
  2 => 'N.E.R.D & Rihanna - Lemon',
  3 => 'RihannaVEVO',
  4 => 'Rihanna - Diamonds',
  5 => 'Rihanna - Work (Explicit) ft. Drake',
  6 => 'Kendrick Lamar - LOYALTY. ft. Rihanna',
  7 => 'Rihanna - Man Down',
  8 => 'Rihanna - Stay ft. Mikky Ekko',
  9 => 'Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For (Official Video) ft. Rihanna' }
entered setMap
Map {
  0 => 'beyonceVEVO',
  1 => 'Beyoncé - Hold Up (Video)',
  2 => 'Beyoncé - Formation',
  3 => 'Beyoncé - Halo',
  4 => 'Ed Sheeran - Perfect Duet (with Beyoncé) [Official Audio]',
  5 => 'Beyoncé - Love On Top (Video Edit)',
  6 => 'Beyoncé - 7/11',
  7 => 'Beyoncé - Sorry (Video)',
  8 => 'Beyoncé - Drunk in Love (Explicit) ft. JAY Z',
  9 => 'J Balvin, Willy William - Mi Gente ft. Beyoncé' }
```

so the code is working and I do find the 10 first songs of each singer however when I go to printJson functions the songs map is empty

Comment: I would add some console logs and check your assumptions. I'm curious what `signers` and `i` equal when line 65 is actually called, because judging by your log, `singers[i]` is undefined.

Comment: @ZacDelventhal I have updated my code, the map is there but I can't update it to get it on the outterscope as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that synchronous code will not wait for asynchronous code to resolve. It will trigger the asynchronous function, then immediately move on to the next line. So in this function:

```
function search10TopForASinger(print) {
    console.log('entered search10TopForASinger ')
    for (var i = 0; i < singers.length; i++) {
        //Gets only 10 results
        var songsMap = singers[i].songs;
        YTAPI.searchFunctions.simpleSearch(singers[i].name).then(
            function (data) {
                setMap(data,songsMap);
            });
    }
    print();
}
```

Your `for` loop will run, triggering each `simpleSearch` call, then it will call `print`, *then* the searches will start to resolve.

---

You could solve this by chaining on a bunch of `.then` calls, or by writing a recursive function that iterated through everything and called itself as a callback. The easiest way is to take advantage of [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Just replace your `for` loop like so:

```
function search10TopForASinger(print) {
    Promise.all(singers.map(function(singer) {
        var songsMap = singer.songs;
        return YTAPI
            .searchFunctions
            .simpleSearch(singer.name)
            .then(function(data) {
                setMap(data, songsMap)
            })
    })).then(function(results) {
        print()
    })
}
```

`Promise.all` takes an array of Promises, which is what `singers.map` will return. It will return a promise itself which will only resolve once every promise in the array has.

---

If you are running Node 8, you could also use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), which will work without as much refactoring:

```
async function search10TopForASinger(print) {
    for (var i = 0; i < singers.length; i++) {
        var songsMap = singers[i].songs;
        var data = await YTAPI.searchFunctions.simpleSearch(singers[i].name);
        setMap(data, songsMap);
    }
    print();
}
```

This basically creates a `.then` chain in the background, so each piece of the function will wait until the `await` resolves to continue. Just remember you have to turn `search10TopForASinger` into an asynchronous function to make that work.